# How to create Multi Axis graph using Chart Pro in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am able to create multi axis graph with the normal graph tool in `iReport version 4.0.1` but I cannot create multi axis graph using *fusion charts* (i.e. ***"Charts Pro"*** tool). I have a deadline to meet on this report and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the Charts Pro do not have a Multiaxis report like the JFreeCharts have.